# jQuery - Remove a table row after it's deleted from database

Tags: jquery

I'm try to remove the deleted table row after it's been successfully deleted from the database but it not working. Here is my code.

**This works:**

```
$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this?"))    
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }
});
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this?"))    
    $.get('cfc/action.cfc?method=deleteLetter&returnformat=plain', {id: $(this).attr('id')},
        function(data){
            if(data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')==='ok'){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This record get deleted here but the table row remains. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: It's a bad method to use a regex to parse your result. You should use JSON instead.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to physically delete the row. It may cause sync problem. After deletion from database, wouldn't it be nice to get/display whole list for the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    var currentRow = $(this);
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this?"))    
    $.get('cfc/action.cfc?method=deleteLetter&returnformat=plain', {id: $(this).attr('id')},
        function(data){
            if(data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')==='ok'){
            currentRow.parent().parent().remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This will work.

When you say this in anonymous method/function then "this" showing to that method or object where code is executed, But if you assign $(this) to variable then you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Use `closest` to find the nearest `tr` element which is the row you want to delete. And also you need to maintain the current row in a variable because in the success handler of `$.get`, `this` will not point to `img` element. Try this

```
$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this?"))    
    $.get('cfc/action.cfc?method=deleteLetter&returnformat=plain', {id: $(this).attr('id')},
        function(data){
            if(data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')==='ok'){
            $this.closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @user281867 - Did you try this?

Comment: I spoke too soon, it DOESN'T work. I also tried changing to $(this).closest('tr').remove(); but it also doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')==='ok'` condition correct?

Comment: Other than that condition other can be the issue in this code. If that condition is satisfied then you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Your element has likely fallen out of scope.

Try to return a JSON string with a success indicator, and explicity parse the return value as JSON.

```
var myElementID = $(this).attr('id');
$.get('cfc/action.cfc?method=deleteLetter&returnformat=plain',
    {id: $(this).attr('id')},
    function(data){ 
        if(data.success){ $('#'+myElementID).parent().parent().remove(); }
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: for this, your AJAX return value would be '{success: true}'

Answer (score 1):

Since it is being executed asynchronously, `this` is no longer pointing to the element you think it is.  Save it in a variable (like target) and then remove that in the callback.

```
$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    var target = this; //Save this here.
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete this?"))    
    $.get('cfc/action.cfc?method=deleteLetter&returnformat=plain', {id: $(this).attr('id')},
        function(data){
            if(data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')==='ok'){
                $(target).closest("tr").remove(); //Remove closest table row here.
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

?

Comment: Andy, thanks for your reply. Yes, I did try what you had suggested, sadly it doesn't work.