# url generation in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".linkDelete").click(function () {
        var userid = $(this).attr("id");
        console.debug("saurabh userid", userid);

        var url = "/delete?id=" + userid;
        var s = "SpringHibernateAnnotations";
        console.debug("saurabh url", url);
        $.ajax({
            url: s + "/delete?id=" + userid,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i have this jquery ajax function which is generating this url
GET http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateAnnotations/SpringHibernateAnnotations/delete?id=253 404 (Not Found) 
instead it should generate 
http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateAnnotations/delete?id=253 404  and if i remove   var s= "SpringHibernateAnnotations"; and keep my url in ajax method as   url : "/delete?id="+userid, it generates http://localhost:8080/delete?id=253 because of which i am not able to enter into application.So how can i generate this proper url http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateAnnotations/delete?id=253

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `/` before the url for `base` path. -

```
var s= "/SpringHibernateAnnotations";
```

If `/` is not present at the start then it will be considered as `relative` path.
The url will be - `http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateAnnotations/delete?id=253`

Comment: thanks it works now,but when the record gets deleted from database it does't reflect in UI page ,if i refresh then only it gets removed.

Comment: If you dont want to reload the page then use jQuery to to remove data from the DOM.

Comment: @b0s3 i am new to jquery can you help me with an example or give me a link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623997/deleting-mysql-table-row-with-jquery-ajax or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153264/jquery-remove-a-table-row-after-its-deleted-from-database

Comment: i used this var respContent = "";
   var rowToDelete = $(".linkDelete").closest("tr"); but it removes all records from ui

Comment: Use `var rowToDelete = $(this).closest("tr");` for current element.